# Mongo/Node.js - Find and remove a specific user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I did a function which takes as parameter an object of type User (with an _id and Strings such as a name, an email, a password, a status, an activity).

The aim of my function is to find a given user and to remove it from the mongo collection "Perso".

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
deleteUser(user){
    var idUser = (Perso.findOne({name:user.name, email:user.email}))._id;
    var o_idUser = ObjectId(idUser);
    return Perso.findOneAndRemove({_id:o_idUser});
}
```

But when I start my web app and try to use this method/function, I get : "An error occured:[object Object]". Do you know if it is directly due to a mistake in this frame of code ? If yes, do you know solution please ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can directly remove the user by name and email like this:

```
deleteUser(user){
    return Perso.findOneAndRemove({ name:user.name, email:user.email });
}
```

as for the error occurred, I think it's better to print the message at least or **stringify** the err using `JSON.stringify(err)` could help to get more information. The `[object Object]` is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you @Yongfeng, but where do I have to insert `JSON.stringify(err)` in order to check that please ?

Comment: @Olscream oh, the exception could be anywhere outside of this delete method. I think you'd better double check where the exception might occur and add `try catch` block for that